# Kibana Histogram unexpected line curve with cumulative value

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Kibana cannot do a the Histogram of the cumulative value of a field as describe at: https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/issues/740

To overcome that I created a separate index where I calculate myself the total and saved it to Elasticsearch.

The mapping looks as follows:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/first_install -d '{
    "settings" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 5
    },
    "mappings" : {
        "fi" : {
            "properties" : {
                "evtTime" : { "type" : "date", "index": "not_analyzed", "format": "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss" },
                "cumulativeValue" : { "type" : "integer", "index": "not_analyzed" }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

The values are saved properly but unexpectedly Kibana does not draw the line i would expect, instead it joins between point that do not exist.

Following is the Kibana sreenshot:

[image]

The line curve should always be increasing since my data set is always increasing, that i can prove by the following events as seen by kibana itself:

[image]

Could it be related to the data formatting I did?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have your setting set to `total` and the interval to `30m`.
What Kibana does, it looks for the value in your selection (table) with the lowest timestamp `819`.
Then it tooks for all values which occurred between the first time-stamp and 30 minutes later.
These values are all summed up `total` and plotted on your graph.
This goes on untill the last value is obtained.

To summarize, Kibana plots the total cumulative value (so actually a cumulative of a cumulative) of all the items within 30 minutes.

Comment: Right, i solved the problem by using "max" instead of "total" in the histogram config

Comment: @isaac.hazan Something to keep an eye out for is the option to disable the so called `zero-fill` now when elasticsearch does not find any values for the `30m` interval it plots a `0` value. It is not implemented yet but I think it's going to be soon https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/issues/934

Comment: yeah thx, I used a kibana patch that has the zero fill and when combined with the max trick the curve looks perfect.

Comment: @isaac.hazan can you send me the details of that? I've been looking for that for over a week now :-)

Comment: I sent i to you over mail. did you get it?

Comment: @isaac.hazan I didn't perhaps you sent it to the wrong email? Thanks for the effort!